# Not enough storage is available to process this command In RSA Encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net

In RSA Encryption With RSACryptoServiceProvider USING ASP.NET C#
, I Got This Error Why?
What is Wrong in My Code?

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string newDcrypt(string text)
    {
        UnicodeEncoding encoder = new UnicodeEncoding();
        string publickey = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Keys/publickey.pem");
        string privatekey = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Keys/privatekey.pem");
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        privatekey = RSA.ToXmlString(true);
        byte[] datatodecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
        RSA.FromXmlString(privatekey);
        byte[] decryptdata = RSA.Decrypt(datatodecrypt, false);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptdata); 
    }
```

Error On This Line Of Code....

```
var decryptdata = RSA.Decrypt(datatodecrypt, false)
```

Encryption Is Fine Here Is Encryption Code....

```
  [WebMethod]
    public string NewEncrypt(string text)
    {
        UnicodeEncoding encoder = new UnicodeEncoding();
        string publickey = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Keys/publickey.pem");
        string privatekey = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Keys/privatekey.pem");

        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        publickey = RSA.ToXmlString(true);
        var datatoencrypt = encoder.GetBytes(text);
        var encryptedbytearray = RSA.Encrypt(datatoencrypt, false);
        RSA.FromXmlString(publickey);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedbytearray);
    }
```

---

Error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: **Not enough storage is available to process this command.** 
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey)
>      at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)
>      at DataEncryptDecrypt.Encryption.newDcrypt(String text) in e:\VS Projects\DataEncryptDecrypt\DataEncryptDecrypt\Encryption.asmx.cs:line 180

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting

Comment: Please provide the exception stacktrace

Comment: Please remove this exception. i am trying to resolve but it still. I searching on google but nothing helpful solution find.

Comment: Is it a 32-bit server?  The message is what is returned when the system's IRPStackSize is inadequate, which is more likely a problem on a 32-bit server.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/106167

Comment: No I am using 64bit machine and the error was generated on my local machine

Comment: Not enough storage is available to process this command

Comment: it does seem as if you are not really using the public keys from your `Keys/...` path btw

Comment: I would recheck the keys (it's content) once again, [it seems that this can happen](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/711165/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command-exception-in-decrypt-while-using-rsacryptoserviceprovider-c) when you're supplying the public key and not the private one...

Comment: and the encoding don't seem to match either...

Comment: dear  Carsten König! i have already encrypt and decrypt with these public and private keys with bouncy castle with same path of keys

Comment: but bouncy castle was not correctly decrypt encrypted data on client side machine. on my machine bouncy castle was done perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and resolved it as follows:

Either you are trying wrong key; or the key does not exist in the csp keystore.